# How do I retain the selected item from a dropdownlist after postback

Tags: asp.net, html-select, selectedindex, selectedtext

The project is for ASP.NET with a VB server side script.

I have a dropdownlist that fills itself up from a datasource.
It posts back with other queries, but problem is that the selected item on the dropdownlist resents to what's on its index 0.

Is there any way that I can retain the value selected after postbacK?

Here's some code:

```
>     Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>         If Not IsPostBack Then
>             Dim qs = Request.QueryString.GetKey(0)
>             Dim po As New ProductObj
>             Select Case qs
>                 Case "br"
>                     Dim x = Request.QueryString("br")
>                     Dim y = Request.QueryString("c")
>                     po.GetCategories(ddlasdf, x)
>                 Case "ca"
>                     Dim y = Request.QueryString("ca")
>                     Dim x = Request.QueryString("b")
>                     po.GetBrands(ddlasdf, y)
>             End Select
>         End If
>     End Sub
>     
>     Protected Sub ddlasdf_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlasdf.SelectedIndexChanged
>         Dim qs1 = Request.QueryString(0)
>         Dim qs2 = Request.QueryString.GetKey(0)
>         MsgBox(ddlasdf.SelectedItem.Text)
>         Select Case qs2
>             Case "br"
>                 Response.Redirect("List.aspx?br=" & qs1 & "&c=" & ddlasdf.Text)
>             Case "ca"
>                 Response.Redirect("List.aspx?ca=" & qs1 & "&b=" & ddlasdf.Text)
>         End Select
>     
>     End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer:

So I solved it myself. Just got the query string index 1 and put it as the text attribute for ddlasdf on page load, inside !IsPostBack. Thanks everyone.

Comment: ASP control maintain there values by default, there must be some other reason, show us some code

Comment: Are you trying to access the selected value before the control is repopulated? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: can you share your code under `page_load` event

Comment: This mostly happens because of the wrong placement of the `Databind()` method. Check the places where you are binding it. if it is in `page.load()` event then it can be the cause.

Comment: i added some codes. no, i'm trying to retain the value selected.

Comment: Are you binding the list in the page load event? If so, are you not binding it inside !IsPostBack?

Comment: @Saurabh I think he is doing it inside the `po.GetBrands`...

Comment: it's actually inside another class being called in page load, inside !IsPostBack, and its named ProductObj.

Comment: @LeiLeyba as I have seen this is most likely the case of Databinding. Check other paths and function executed on postback that might be Doing the Databinding. Before reaching the TextChanged event.

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls thanks. actually, the code wasn't there when I commented.

Comment: `Response.Redirect("List.aspx?br=" & qs1 & "&c=" & ddlasdf.Text)` shouldn't it be `Response.Redirect("List.aspx?br=" & qs1 & "&c=" & ddlasdf.SelectedItem.Text)`

Comment: @LeiLeyba place a breakpoint in page.load() and check on the postback the ddlasdf stacktrace if there is the item present that are populated  previously. if so then check your code as I said before.

Comment: @Saurabh ... ok and does not matter..

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls sir please speak in english, i'm new at ASP. lol

Comment: So I solved it myself. Just got the query string index 1 and put it as the text attribute for ddlasdf on page load, inside !IsPostBack. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Ok.. @LeiLeyba then I think this is the perfect place to turn the page and study the `Asp.net Page life cycle` and events. Good luck.

Comment: @LeiLeyba - You should post the solution as an answer, so it is easier to find in the future (not everyone reads comments).

Comment: sure @Leigh, thansks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it myself. Just got the query string index 1 and put it as the text attribute for ddlasdf on page load, inside !IsPostBack. Thanks everyone.